# How to unlock WeChat money as a foreigner in China?

Tags: china, payment

I was using WeChat pay efficiently, friends funded me (me handing them cash from ATM).

Then I got some from a dodgy source (LocalBitcoins) and 2 days later I had a situation in a shop when I couldn’t pay.

Trying to figure out what to do to unlock the money.

I’m not a Chinese guy, I don’t have Chinese bank or debit card and I don’t want other people to eternally suffer because of me.

Advice much appreciated.

[image]

**EDIT / UPDATE:**

Managed to open the that screen as a website: https://kf.qq.com/touch/sappfaq/170511FfQzQf170511mIRf2u.html?scene_id=kf4030

> Login [WeChat]->[I]->[Wallet]->[Bank Card] Add a bank card according to the prompt.

Maybe I should rephrase the question - how to add a bank card without a bank card? Can I ask a local person?

Comment: What does the text say if you run it through a translation service like e.g. Google Translate?

Comment: That means you must finish the personal verification by registering a Chinese bank account. Actually, it is very inconvenient to use WeChat Pay/AliPay without a bank card. There is another question posted on this platform on how to open a bank account in China as a foreigner.

Comment: I live in China as a foreigner. I can't tell you how to unlock wechat pay without a bank account but i can tell you the phone number you logged into wechat with is connected to your passport. So when a government agency or wechat sees anything suspicious, they shut it down.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.

Comment: Has not returned to clarify what? After some stress and massive inconvenience, it was automagically unlocked. Thank you.