# Is it really possible to open bank account in China without a permanent address - does it mean the card is provided on the spot?

Tags: china, money

Asking because my WeChat account got blocked: [How to unlock WeChat money as a foreigner in China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125923/how-to-unlock-wechat-money-as-a-foreigner-in-china)

Doing research on how to open a bank account.

1. https://www.saporedicina.com/english/open-bank-account-china/
2. https://transferwise.com/gb/blog/opening-a-bank-account-in-china
3. https://www.travelchinacheaper.com/open-china-bank-account

None of these three articles mention an address.

Does it mean that the AliPay card is provided right there on the spot?

Comment: When you say AliPay card, do you mean a bank card that AliPay supports, or UnionPay (akin to Visa, LINK, Mastercard) card? If I remember correctly AliPay does not issue any cards (they skipped a generation and skipped straight to phones), but I might be wrong.

Comment: You are confused with a bank card and AliPay. AliPay is a mobile wallet service much like WeChat Pay, which you cannot connect to WeChat account.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can open a Chinese bank account** and get the card as a foreign traveler. The detailed steps are described [in this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73567/27223) but to summarize (and add a little bit more detail):

- You need the passport and a valid Chinese phone number.
- Depending on banks, you need initial deposit. Usually 5 or 10 CHY cash is fine.
- You need an address to fill in, but the hotel or Airbnb is fine.
- The whole process takes 30 to 60 minutes.

The bank card is provided on the spot, which you can register to your WeChat account.

I recommend opening a bank account at one of four big banks. However, the Bank of China does not allow non-residents to open a bank account.

Also, if you don't speak Chinese, go to a branch at city center in 1st-tier cities.